# How to access external MySQL from within Vagrant?

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to access a MySQL database in the public network my host is on.
I need to access the MySQL database from within Vagrant by connecting to the DB via PHP's mysql_connect.

I have an ubuntu/trusty64 Vagrant box running Apache2, PHP and MySQL through the old mysql extension.

When I try to connect to the database on the network via the DB server's IP address, it says Can't connect to database.

What do I need to do to be able to access external servers from within the Vagrant guest?

Comment: so you have the DB in another machine than your host ? and your host can connect to this machine ? whats your network config of the vagrant VM, do you use `bridge` ?

Comment: I have configured my vm to use a forwarded port. It is currently config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080

Comment: I could connect after all, I just had something wrong in my code. ^_^;
I mixed up the dbname and password variables.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I could connect properly after all. I just mixed up the variables for my password and the DB name in my code. ^_^;

Comment: So if this is an unreproducible one-off, maybe it would make sense to delete the question and the answer?